# Change the error key of Laravel 8 credential matching validation?

Tags: laravel, error-handling, laravel-8

After I changed this in the LoginController:

```
/**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->input('login_email'),
            'password' => $request->input('login_password'),
        ];
    }
```

I am able to get "login_email" as a key why a user tries to login without filling out the email input.

```
"login_email" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "The login email field is required."
  ]
```

But when the credentials do not match the error key is "email" and I want it to be "login_email" as well:

```
"email" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "These credentials do not match our records."
  ]
```

What do I need to do in order to change the matching credentials error key?

I saw that in the `resources/lang/en/auth.php` file the key for the "These credentials do not match our records." is 'failed' is there a way to rename the "email" key to "failed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is override this function in the LoginController no all is as I wanted it:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'login_email' => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ])->redirectTo('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal behaviour,

on first one you are checking $request which `'login_email'` is form field, on second one `$db_result` which `"email"` is field on table.

One way to solve is to rename `'login_email'` to `email`,

Comment: I need it to be "login_email", is there a way to change it? Because I want to use "login_emai" and "signup_email" in two forms that are on same page.